# Modifing an HTML tag without loosing attached event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syncfusion

I'm trying to **modify the text inside a list element** that contains also another html element, a  that is used to remove the list element on click.

The HTML structure is like the following:

```
<ul class="e-ul e-boxes">
    <li class="e-options" data-value="1">January<span class="e-icon e-close" unselectable="on"></span></li>
    <li class="e-options" data-value="2">February<span class="e-icon e-close" unselectable="on"></span></li>
</ul>
```

The HTML above **is produced by a widget** (ejDropdDownList) when the user selects a month from the drop down list. 
This is how it looks like:

[image]

**The  elements inside the LIs are the X that have an event listener attached by the widget, and on click, the relative LI is removed.**

I have added a script that once the user selects more than 4 months, the **month names are abbreviated** in the text list of the drop down, but **I lose the associated click event** to the  elements.

```
function sortSelectedMonthText() {
        var mylist = $('#months_container ul.e-ul');
        var listItems = mylist.children('li').get();
        listItems.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).data('value') - $(b).data('value');
        });


        $.each(listItems, function (idx, itm) {
            if (listItems.length > 4) {
                //more than 4 months selected: replace w abbreviated text
                var monthVal = $(itm).data('value');
                var monthName = monthNames[monthVal - 1];
                itm.innerHTML= itm.innerHTML.replace(monthName,monthName.substring(0,3));
            }
            mylist.append(itm);
        });
}
```

and this is the results:
[image] but the X doesn't work anymore!

Here you can find the full working code: https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/vpdrjvq0

How can I **avoid to lose the listeners**?

Or is there a way to identify the listener and **re-attach** it to the  once I've modified the LIs text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to operate on the **Text Node**, not on the parent li element in order to preserve the others properties of the item and children.
So the function should be fixed as follow:

```
function sortSelectedMonthText() {
    var mylist = $('#months_container ul.e-ul');
    var listItems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listItems.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).data('value') - $(b).data('value');
    });

    $.each(listItems, function (idx, itm) {
        if (listItems.length > 4) {
            var monthVal = $(itm).data('value');
            var monthName = monthNames[monthVal - 1];
            itm.firstChild.textContent = itm.firstChild.textContent.substring(0,3);
            console.log(itm);
        }
        mylist.append(itm);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `.innerHTML` you are overriding the HTML including any attached events. Try and assign the trimmed month name to `itm.innerTEXT` instead:
`itm.innerTEXT = itm.innerTEXT.replace(monthName,monthName.substring(0,3));`

Answer (score 1):

You can [`detach`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) the `span` element before modifying the `li` and re-insert it, it'll keep its associated listeners:

```
var span = $(itm).children('span').detach();
itm.innerHTML = itm.innerHTML.replace(monthName, monthName.substring(0, 3));            
$(itm).append(span);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I prefer Mattia Pontonio solution.